# Connect and scan a pipeline

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-purview

When I try to get the lineage of a pipeline I have the following message on screen, for info my purview is indeed status connected from synapse.

[image]

Comment: Did you refer-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/how-to-link-azure-data-factory and limitations?

Comment: yes, also refer it

Comment: Did you check the status of Purview in the Manage>>External Connection?